# python 3 как читать файл если в нем есть иероглифы и тд

Tags: python-3.x, файлы, кодировка

подскажите пожалуйста как мне прочитать файл в котором есть непонятные символы, код:

```py
f = open("C:/Users/Андрей/Desktop/fdf/menu.txt", "r")
f2 = open("C:/Users/Андрей/Desktop/fdf/menu2.txt", "w")
for line in f:
    line = str(line)
    f2.write(line)
f2.close()
f.close()
```

мне нужно прочитать информацию по строчно из файла "menu.txt" и записать эту информацию по строчно в файл "menu2.txt",
Ошибка:

```
File "C:\python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 51: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй забить латиницу, если ОК, то ищи по сообщению от терминала. Он не понимает кодировку (кириллицу) .
File "C:\python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 51: character maps to**